# Xcode 14 on Ventura OS stock and restart my Mac

Tags: flutter, firebase

I need help please. I updated my MacBook Pro 2017 OS from Monterey to Ventura (now on 13.1) which required me to update my xCode to xCode 14 (now on 14.2) as well. However since I made the update to xCode 14.xx, my pc get stocked and restart after a while of launching the xCode 14. I cannot build iOS app anymore. Please any solution to this issue? Thanks

I have tried uninstalling the Xcode and then install again. Reboot the system with command. But no solution yet

Comment: try NVRAM reset.

Comment: I have done that, but no solution, you can read where I use reboot with command

Comment: tested in safe mode? and check your shutdown logs too

Comment: The last time I checked the shutdown log, it was making a reference to insufficient memory, but I have up to 80GB free memory space

Comment: memory here probably means your RAM